Why was a temp ban made permanent when I didn't post anything while I was banned?
I'm NOT trying to get the ban lifted; I just want to know why my status changed to permanent w/o any new posts.
i'm wondering if improper factors were used, like my posts on other sites, or my profile.
That WOULD be improper, right?
If I get a serious answer, great. If I get an evasive, hostile, or null answer, or if this question disappears; then I know the ban was not legitimate -- it was based on things you won't talk about because it's manifestly unfair.
Again, I'm not trying to change anything, just understand it because this kind of mysterious treatment is frequently done to us autistics. The one thing that identifies these incidents is that the perpetrator is always unable to explain it.

The ban is only lifted by you editing your questions (cf. the mother meta FAQ on it). AFAIK, it's always been permanent (in the sense that, if you do nothing then you will never get it lifted).

But I'm not asking for the ban to be lifted. I want to know why I was banned for asking serious, obviously okay questions.

On second thought, never mind. I'm being naive again. I'm in a hostile environment and am unable to perceive it. That just happens sometimes. No information that will enable me to improve myself will likely be forthcoming.  That fact identifies the ban as improper, even if I can never know why it happened. So I can at least extract that useful information.

I probably should be swapped the order of the sentences: it is, to my knowledge, a permanent ban provided you do nothing. If you start editing your questions to be positively received, the ban can be lifted. If you read the link I provided (which should be provided when you try posting a question), there is enough information on how to improve your questions.

Also, as stated in the link I gave, the ban is algorithmically determined, which means no human was involved in applying the ban to you.

Another possibility is that one or more of your questions were subsequently downvoted/closed/deleted.

I understand its frustrating but your last two paragraphs (and your comment above) are false and biased. You, like many other uses who have a problem with this site, make the false assumption that everyone else here is hostile to you, which simply isn't the case. Downvotes/closures/deletions are not primarily intended to be personal attacks on the poster. So please view objectively instead of through tinted glasses.

Your current restrictions on posting are the result of an automated algorithm. The exact criteria are secret — we don't know them either.  But the algorithm does look at your "question record." Each question you ask is a positive, but downvoted, closed, or deleted questions are negatives. A number of your recent questions have been downvoted, closed, and deleted: triple damage.
I'm not aware of any distinction between being "temporarily" versus "permanently" restricted from asking questions.  But it's possible that one or more of your closed, unanswered questions were deleted automatically after some weeks of inactivity.  Whether that affects your status is not clear to me.
As I understand it, even "permanently banned" users can ask a question after six months of inactivity.

Ty for an answer blissfully clean of the emotional offal I drown in.

Emotional offal is the worst. I hope your support network is robust. Best wishes.

@MissUnderstands It is reported that deleting your questions results in a heavy penalty.  The idea is. as I understand it, to encourage users to edit posts, not delete them because deleting isn't constructive.

I don't care about points. I threw my cs dept semester valedictorian cert away and didn't tell anyone  because it would look like bragging (yes really). I only went there to learn stuff and that's why I come here. As an autistic, I learned that when people get all pissed off for no reason, I walk away.

We don't know. The exact details of the algorithm are secret to everyone except Stack Exchange employees. But essentially it's because you have a lot of deleted, downvoted, and closed questions.
This ban is automated- no person was involved in applying it, and as far as I know nobody can manually remove it. The details that are publicly available (and what you can do about it if you change your mind) can be found here.
